# Recursive functions Js

Tags: javascript

I have numbers array, through my_number function I create a random numer, if it already exist in the array, I call  the function again and create a new random number, if it is not in the array I send it to it through push.

Unfortunately it sems to send all numbers again and again until browser crashes.

How could I fix this.

Thanks for your help

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function mainFunction(){
    function my_number(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
        for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i] === randomNumber){
                my_number();
            }else{
                numbers.push(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }
    
    my_number();
}

mainFunction();
```

Comment: Every time you push another number onto the array, `numbers.length` changes.

Comment: Oh, and also you're comparing `i`, not `numbers[i]`.

Comment: I already changed i for numbers[i] and I get this in console : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @JP You can use `numbers.includes(randomNumber)`. The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Comment: Checking for duplicates doesn't come for free. And you want most numbers out of a given set of numbers. That means the further you progress, the more duplicates will you probably generate, and the slower you will progress. A better approach here would be to generate a list with all possible values, shuffle it and then take the first *n* values from that shuffled list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `my_number` function, you have called `my_number` again inside `for-loop` and it is needed to call `my_number` function with the result of the `for-loop`.

So it is needed to get the result if the `randomNumber` has existed or not through `for-loop` and based on that, you need to decide to call the function again or not.

1. Preferred Way

   ```js
   const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

   function mainFunction(){
     function my_number(){
       const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
       const isExisted = numbers.some((item) => item === randomNumber);
       if (isExisted) {
         my_number();
       } else {
         numbers.push(randomNumber);
       }
     }
     my_number();
   }

   mainFunction();
   console.log(numbers);
   ```
2. Regarding your CodeBase.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function mainFunction(){
  function my_number(){
    const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
    let isExisted = false;
    for (let index = 0; index < numbers.length; index ++) {
      if (numbers[index] === randomNumber) {
        isExisted = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isExisted) {
      my_number();
    } else {
      numbers.push(randomNumber);
    }
  }
  my_number();
}

mainFunction();
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with the code.

- As Pointy pointed out, `i` should be `numbers[i]` to compare the array element instead of the index.
- You have a function definition inside another function, which is fine, but the only thing the outer function does is call the inner function, so it's redundant.
- `numbers.push(randomNumber)` should be done outside the for loop because it would otherwise only check if `randomNumber` matches the first element and ignores the rest.
- After the call to `my_number` in the for loop, you need a `return` statement to prevent the loop from continuing after detecting failure.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function my_number() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] === randomNumber){
            my_number();
            return;
        }
    }
    numbers.push(randomNumber);
}

my_number();

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

This question should include more details and clarify the problem. According to given details, Please check the following answer.

```
// I have numbers array
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function mainFunction() {
    // through my_number function  
    function my_number() {
        // I create a random numer
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);

        var isExists = numbers.includes(randomNumber);

        // if it already exist in the array
        if (isExists) {
            // I call the function again
            my_number();
        } else { // if it is not in the array
            // I send it to it through push
            numbers.push(randomNumber);
        }

    }

    my_number();
}

mainFunction();
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are exactly trying to do, but I messed with your code. Try this code out and see if its your expected output. (This is probably wrong tbh. Sorry.)

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function mainFunction(){
    function my_number(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
    
        for(let i in numbers){
            if(numbers[i] == randomNumber){
                return;
            }else{
                numbers.push(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    my_number();
}

mainFunction();
console.log(numbers);
```